# How do I Configure IIS to accept POST requests?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know by default IIS doesn't accept post requests how can I change this setting.
Can someone walk me through changing this (step by step).. Please?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't accept POST requests? Also: which version of IIS? The UI is very different... Finally, this *might* be more suited to serverfault, but tbh I think the question needs some clarification before it would be answerable even there.

Comment: What do you mean "by default IIS doesn't accept post requests"???

Comment: @Marc, I was just about to ask the very same thing, well, the first bit anyway.

Comment: By default it does accept POST, but not some other Verbs (DELETE for example).  What version of IIS are you using.

Comment: I'm trying to run this Facebook app off our servers and was told that IIS doesn’t allow POST requests to html files by default. 

I know this to be true but how do I change this?

Comment: Posts requests are sent TO the server FROM html files... not the other way around

Comment: Voting to move to serverfault... @quakkels: yes but you have to point this POST at a resource in his case an HTML file, perhaps IIS has some default policy of not allowing POST requests for `*.html`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using IIS 6 and lower:

From inside the IIS management screen right click on your website or virtual directory.  Go to `Properties` then go to the `Home Directory` or `Virtual Directory` tab and click on the `Configuration` button.  From there you can add/update extensions and what Verbs are accepted.

---

If you are using IIS 7:

From inside the IIS management screen click on `Handler Mappings`.  You can add by clicking the links on the right side or double-click on an item to edit it.

[image: picture of handler mappings location]

Comment: OK, but which handler mappings to you need to add and/or edit?

Comment: this is well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440277/how-do-i-enable-http-put-and-delete-for-asp-net-mvc-in-iis

Comment: I appreciate this is a dated question, but after many hours of searching this was the closest to my issue - whereby I was POSTing to the server but it was being refused due to the size. 2 good resources on Microsoft to assist in helping set the above up and resolve my issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/solution-for-request-entity-too-large-error/ba-p/501134

Answer (score -1):

If it's related to an asp.net app you might be able to set it in your web.config [as described here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/741.cfm).

Comment: I wouldn't suggest editing configurations at a server wide level unless needed for some niche usecase.