# Can't call delete function from Ajax jQuery to Asp.net API function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm using jQuery 3.2.1. I'm trying to call API by Ajax jQuery.

I'm following an example and code like this:

```
(() => {
    function delTest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3413/api/person?ID=100',
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "": "Sourav Kayal" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

and API

```
   public class personController : ApiController  
    {  
        [HttpDelete]  
        public string Delete([FromUri] int ID, [FromBody] String name)  
        {  
            return "Delete Operation" + "ID:- " + ID + "Name:- " + name;  
        }  
    }


protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

However, it's not working now.

Returns an error: 404 Not found

Comment: Have you added `[RoutePrefix("api/person")]` above the `public class personController` ?

Comment: Are you sure the hard coded port number of local host is actually the port in use?

Comment: not yet @Arulkumar

Comment: the port is not in use @kaffekopp

Comment: I tried to put `[RoutePrefix("api/person")]` , still not working

Comment: Then I think you should correct the `url` string with the port you are using. @NguyễnMinhVương

Comment: It's correct port and URL @kaffekopp, still not working

Comment: PUT and DELETE might not be enabled if you're hosting in IIS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440277/how-do-i-enable-http-put-and-delete-for-asp-net-mvc-in-iis

Comment: You are passing only ID from the front end but on the server you are expecting name too. That's why it can not find your delete method.

Comment: @Gaurav ajax config included `data: { "": "Sourav Kayal" }`

Comment: ok did you try adding name as into the data, something like this data: { "name": "Sourav Kayal" }?

Comment: just edited @Gaurav, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am using below code and its working fine on my machine. I think you need to add method name delete in the URL, it should look like "http://localhost:3413/api/person/Delete?ID=100"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function delTest() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3413/person/Delete?ID=100',
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { name: "Sourav Kayal" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
            }
        });
    }
</script> 

<input type="button" name="delete" onclick="delTest()" value="makeCall"/>
```

and API code:

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpDelete]
        public string Delete([FromUri] int ID, [FromBody] String name)
        {
            return "Delete Operation" + "ID:- " + ID + "Name:- " + name;
        }
```

Comment: Is this code is working for you? If so can you please mark it as answer.