# My Entity Framework Core API works fine locally, but fails with a 405 error in production

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0, iis-8.5

I have a .NetCore 3.1 API project that uses Entity Framework.

It is working perfectly when I run it locally from Visual Studio.

However, after publishing to a production IIS 8.5 server, I get the following errors when I try to hit an API that uses PUT on the production server.

> xhr.js:178 PUT https://nationalparks.xyz.gov/api/plants/91 405 (Method
>   Not Allowed)

My controller begins like this:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutPlant(long id, [FromBody] Plant plant)
    {
      ...
    }
```

And client-side looks like this:

```
    await axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "api/plants/" + plant.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(plant),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
```

Honestly I'm stumped...I'm not sure why it's doing that.

I've seen a few posts saying to modify the web.config, but my app uses appsettings.json, not a web.config.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: May be you need to configure your IIS to accept put/delete headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind the issue is the WebDAV module intercepted the request. to resolve the issue you could follow the below workaround.

1)Remove WebDAV from your system:

open control panel-> “Turn Windows Features On or Off”->un-ticking the WebDAV publishing checkbox.

[image]

or

2)Add below code in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>    
  <modules>        
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
  </modules>    
  <handlers>        
    <remove name="WebDAV" />    
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Please remember that after doing these changes you can nit use the WebDAV module in iis.

Answer (score 1):

dotnet core applications do use `web.config` when running under IIS. You will notice that the `publish` command makes a `web.config` file that tells IIS which DLL to run for your application.

I think I had the same issue a while back. I fixed it by adding lines to `web.config` to remove the WebDAV modules. See this answer for more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12443578/65432