# ASP.NET Core 5, HttpPut request with parameters from body always returns Http 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, iis

First of all, this is my first post on this website. And also this is my first application that I am trying to publish onto a web server. So forgive me if some things aren't that clear, or not as they are supposed to.

The problem is as follows: when I send a PUT request to my backend, I always get a "Http 400 Bad request" error. This problem showed up when I uploaded the backend to an IIS hosting server. When I run the application on localhost, the problem doesn't occur.

I've created a simple version of a PUT request, that is as follows:

```
  [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
  public ActionResult PutTest(int id, [FromBody]TestClass model)
  {
     return Ok(model.Prop1);          
  }
```

The TestClass is as follows:

```
namespace WebApi.Models.Accounts
{
   public class TestClass
   {
      public string Prop1 { get; set; }
      public string Prop2 { get; set; }
   }
}
```

When I run this code on `https://localhost:5000` for instance, it works fine. But when I deploy the backend to my domain, let's say `https://www.mySite.app`, it always returns a bad request error.

I've tried simplifying the code even further. And noticed that when I only ask for a singe parameter in the PUT action like below, it works fine.

```
  [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
  public ActionResult PutTest(int id)
  {
     return Ok(id);          
  }
```

The `web.config` file that I am using is quite simple, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
         </handlers>
         <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
            <handlerSettings>
               <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="file" />
               <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value=".\logs\aspnetcore-debug.log"/>
            </handlerSettings>
         </aspNetCore>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

I'm testing my backend with Postman. I am able to successfully send requests to all other Http functions in my backend, except for this PUT request with parameters in the body.

I'm stuck at this for a few days now, and can't seem to find the solution. So any help would be appreciated. All other Http classes work fine btw, POST, GET, DELETE and so on..

Comment: declare method as `[HttpPut]
  public ActionResult PutTest(TestClass model)
  {
     return Ok(model.Prop1);          
  }`

Comment: @viveknuna I do not see how that would help; OP's setup is very normal and should work fine. Having the ID as a param to the route is used all the time. In any case, could you explain WHY your suggestion would fix the issue, and perhaps what, in your opinion, causes the issue?

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440277/how-do-i-enable-http-put-and-delete-for-asp-net-mvc-in-iis) out

Comment: @viveknuna I've tried this solution, but it also gives me the same error response.

Comment: @Alexander, also tried to edit my web.config file as mentioned in the post you've pointed out. But also without succes. I always end up with the same 400 - bad request error code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Fiddler or something to check the raw request/response when it fails? That would also help on top of what is suggested by S. ten Brinke above.

These pages from Microsoft would also help you troubleshoot and capture the IIS logs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/troubleshooting-http-400-errors-in-iis
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/aspnet/error-logging-http-apis

Comment: I've not looked into this yet, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code to test but no problem was found. I suggest you use FRT to see which module has the problem.

[image]

You can use FRT to catch 400 error and then view detailed logs, for more information about FRT, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: thanks for your answer. My website is being hosted by an external company. I'm only able to upload/edit files on the server. So i'm not able to catch the errors on the server side through FRT.

Comment: You can try to deploy the project in the local IIS to see if this problem occurs.