# facebook app throws 405 error

Tags: facebook

I added a html game page to facebook developer page as app and it throws 405 method not allowed error. Could some one help me on this?
App details: http://apps.facebook.com/kannayya/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook loads applications via POST. That error is not Facebook related, it's an error that is being thrown by your server. Make sure that POSTs are allowed, and allowed for the specific canvas URL that you've set in the developer console for your app.

Comment: NIck, But its just a simple html file in my server. How can I allow posts. Could you please guide me on that?

Comment: I'm not familiar on how to configure that outside of apache. I would recommend running a quick search for enabling POST on IIS. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472429/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-accept-post-requests.