# Nodejs + facebook canvas integration with external app url

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, continuous-integration, http-status-code-405

We have created an application, and want to show that in Facebook Canvas. Now, when we put the url which contains index.html we get 405 error and website does not load.

I did google and also found some solutions like we require php or aspx type files on the server, and found link like this
[facebook app throws 405 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804161/facebook-app-throws-405-error)

but we don't use these files and also don't have apache or IIS server. so, I came on the conclusion that I would call to my subdomain which can be js file i.e. [https://www.abcexamdfdf.com/index.js](https://www.subdomain.com/index.js) and index.js contains data which redirects to our website i.e. https://www.xdfdfdfdfee.com that is on another server.

so, I need nodejs code which redirect to our website.

Thanks

Comment: You are not allowed to redirect away from Facebook

Comment: I want to redirect from any nodejs or js code, which will be called from canvas. And Facebook canvas url will call my application server. and instead of using index.php or index.aspx..I want to use index.js that code will be on my subdomain.

Comment: that´s not how node.js works...you should read some basic tutorials. you don´t just put a js-file on your server and call that in the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nodejs - Redirect url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: @luschn
I am getting following error when I use html page in the facebook canvas url

`url Code: MethodNotAllowed 
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource. Method: POST 
ResourceType: OBJECT 
RequestId: E45DD78BE4636CBFdd 
HostId: YONdyxkoRxeElKqBdddDikS9TEUMV8fN+Tz/CNFgDioGGkH75OfNhTsGNUbYWz3xHcRHOP`

so, How http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url would helpful to me ? and where should I put the code given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url

Comment: without your node.js source it´s nearly impossible to help. you need to update your question and put some code in it, and step by step explanations of what you tried so far.

Comment: @luschn I don't have any node.js code right now.

Comment: @luschn
I am adding https://helloldd.com so, it gives me 405 error. so, My idea is to put https://hellod.com/index.js in facebook canvas url. and index.js will have code which will be redirecting to original app on another server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63998/discussion-between-rishabh-shah-and-luschn).

Comment: as i said, you need to read some basic tutorials about node.js before asking questions about node.js on stackoverflow. this is not a place where people spend their time to teach you how node.js works for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this problem.
We have put our application/data server url in facebook canvas url which is js file extention, and that redirects to our portal url.