# Only accept get & post verb

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

Now I have a website, and run it on IIS & ASP.NET 4.0 .

But now the website has some security problems. "Vulnerability: ASP.NET DEBUG Method Enabled"

So I would like to have my website only accept GET & POST requests.

And I have a MVCHandler by myself, so if I change the verb of the MVCHandler, the request end of ".qs" will implement this rule. Below is the control in web.config. 
`<add name="MvcHttpHandler" verb="GET,POST" path="*.qs" type="Suryani.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler" />`

But my website still has a part of WEBFORM, end by ".aspx". I don't know how to set up the IIS or web.config to make ".aspx" only allow GET & POST.

Any insights/advice/references will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use...

```
[HttpPost] or [HttpGet]
```

on your controller methods

for example...

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult MyMethod(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(SomeMethod(ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.Error(e.Message, e);
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!But I have many controllers in the system, so I want to fix this problem by web.config or IIS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> But now it has some security problems.

Says who?

> "Vulnerability: ASP.NET DEBUG Method Enabled"

Search the web for *"ASP.NET disable debug"* could help you to pages like [Vulnerability Database | Rapid7](http://www.rapid7.com/vulndb/lookup/http-asp-dot-net-debug-enabled), [Don’t run production ASP.NET Applications with debug=”true” enabled - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx) and so on.

> And I have a MVCHandler by myself, so if I change the verb of the MVCHandler, the request end of ".qs" will implement this rule.

What?

> But my website still has a part of WEBFORM, end by ".aspx". I don't know how to set up the IIS or web.config to make ".aspx" only allow GET & POST.

[Configure your handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472429/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-accept-post-requests).