# IIS 6 / ASP.NET Reading POST request as GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I have an ASP.net C# application that relies on the `IsPostBack` property.  The application is failing because GET requests are mysteriously being sent.

I'm monitoring requests & responses, as well as the `Request.RequestType` property.

Outgoing requests are **definintely** POST requests, however, the `Request.RequestType` property is consitently GET.

I've checked the IIS 6 accepted HTTP Verbs as suggested in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472429/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-accept-post-requests/3472460#3472460).  The POST verb is always allowed.  I've also checked the Web.config file, and there are no Verb restrictions.

Anyone have any clue why IIS is changing POST requests to GET requests?

Thanks!

**Update**

- Wireshark monitoring on the server is showing that POST requests are being received as well as the proper request body.
- IIS logs are showing that POST requests are properly being received
- `Request.RequestType` Is still GET....

**Update 2**

I ended up solving the problem by re-installing all ASP.NET 4 packages on the web server.

**The issue has surfaced again!**  This time, however, it is selective!  **Chrome**, **Firefox**, and **IE** requests are being interpretted fine!  When I run my load tests from **JMeter** POST is being interpretted as GET.

Does anyone have any clue what is going on?  Does this have something to do with the requesting IP / agent?  Does ASP.NET keep a record of IPs / agents?

Comment: Do you have any HTTP modules or ISAPI filters?  They could be changing the data before your code sees it.

Comment: I have no ISAPI filters specific to the site.  I have ASP.NET_4.0.30319.0 filter running for all websites at a Low Priority.

Comment: As for modules, the site is running:

* ADXStudio
* ScriptModule?  (System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, version 3.5.0.0)
* A custom module

Comment: The system is very buggy, and I did not create it myself so there are many parts that I am unfamiliar with.  What exactly would I be looking for within these modules?

Comment: Can you remove the ADXStudio & custom modules and see what happens?

Comment: Tried this.  Unfortunately the site depends on these modules & will not load at all without them.