# Debug request as it passes through HttpModules

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-6

So I'm encountering this weird issue where HTTP POST requests are being received by the first page of my application as GET requests.  IIS logs the requests as POST, so it's something that's happening within ASP.NET.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can set a breakpoint before the HttpModules & monitor the state of the request as it passes through the modules.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: What is generating the request?

Comment: Post your controller and the HTML / JS that sends the request.

Comment: Requests are being generated by jMeter (recorded from a Chrome browser).  See [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066362/iis-6-asp-net-reading-post-request-as-get) for more details.

Comment: Pluc -- all pages that require `IsPostBack` to function fail.  Checking `Request.HttpMethod` on any of these pages results in `GET`.  Regardless, I'm simply wondering how I can set a breakpoint at the very beginning, to check `Request.HttpMethod` before the request proceeds through the HttpModules.  Is this possible?

Comment: I would try to check what your request is on the client side, is that possible? If you're using something like IE, you can look at the network activity to see exactly what your request contains.

Comment: I've already followed the requests.  Wiresharked on the client side & serverside, as well as viewed in IIS logs.  It shows up as a POST request the whole way through.  The entire request is intact (variables, etc).  The only change is the method has been somehow swapped to GET