# Web Api with Sitecore 8.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I've been trying to get Web Api to work with Sitecore 8.1.

I installed this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krusen.Sitecore.WebApi.Custom/ and I modified the `ConfigureWebApi` to the following:

```
public class ConfigureWebApi
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ReplaceControllerSelector);
    }

    private static void ReplaceControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IHttpControllerSelector),
            new CustomHttpControllerSelector(config, new NamespaceQualifiedUniqueNameGenerator()));
    }
}
```

However, whenever I use post requests, I get the following error:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method
>   'POST'."}. Get requests work.

This is the implementation of the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/authentication")]
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    [Route("email")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Login([FromBody] string email)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think something must be wrong with your route configuration or you might have used the `HttpPostAttribute` from the MVC namespaces instead of `System.Web.Http`. I guess you are posting to `http://yourdomain.com/api/authentication/email`?

Comment: @SørenKruse yes, the URL I test with is as you write, with a random string in the body.
I am using the System.Web.Http.HttpPost attribute

Comment: Okay, have you tried without the `API Default` route that you added?

Comment: @SørenKruse If I remove the route I get the normal Sitecore error: The requested document was not found, along with the HTML of course

Comment: Then something is wrong. I'm pretty sure it should work out of the box with 8.1. Could you check where `ConfigureWebApi` is placed in the `initialize` pipeline using `showconfig.aspx`? It should be placed right after `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Pipelines.ServicesWebApiInitializer, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore`

Comment: @SørenKruse it is placed where it should be

Comment: @Hykalos I suppose GET is working over a similar url, if yes: try this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472429/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-accept-post-requests

Comment: @SilentTremor sorry, but I don't get what the fix is supposed to be? It shouldn't even accept GET requests due to the `HttpPost` attribute, but it completely ignores it apparantly

Comment: @Hykalos create a GET endpoint under same route and test if you can access it, if yes you your IIS is blocking POST. Example:  [Route("email")]
    [HttpGet]
    public int GetTest()
    {
        return 0;
    }

Comment: @SilentTremor If I use the `MapHttpRoute` function, it works using `GET`, however if I only have the `[HttpPost]` function, it uses this function even though it is marked with `HttpPost` i.e. ignoring the tag

Comment: @Hykalos if you are 100% sure you can use GET and POST isn't working  on over your web api it means your IIS does not allow to your website to accept POST search on SO for guidelines.

Comment: @Hykalos I've just tried on a clean install of Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003. It works without the line you have added in the `Process(..)` method (the part with `API Default`), but with the line you have added I get the same error as you - Method not allowed.

Comment: @SørenKruse Just tried reinstalling it and not modify it, however I get the same `The requested document was not found` error... I'm using `Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151207)`

Comment: @Hykalos I've just tried on a clean install of 8.1 rev. 151207 as well without any issues. Do you have any other routes defined elsewhere that might interfere?

Comment: @SørenKruse There shouldn't be. The only implementation there is, is Windsor Castle for the standard MVC (tried disabling it along with your suggestions) and an implementation of an interface.

Comment: @SørenKruse A clean install did the trick. Must have done something funky to mess it up. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Hykalos Glad you got it to work.

Comment: @SørenKruse Fun fact: if I name my ApiController `AuthenticationController`, it gives the `Document not found` Sitecore error. Might have been the error all along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the error was. When my controller was called AuthenticationController it gave the following error:

> The requested document was not found

If I called it something else, the web api worked as a charm e.g.

```
public TestController : ApiController {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Comment: Correct. Authentication controller is one of Sitecore's already. In fact it's the first one registered!

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of what controllers Sitecore has registered?