# How to Accept POST request with IIS?

Tags: asp.net, xml, post, iis

I need to develop a web service to accept and save XML files transfered via POST requests. The chosen platform is IIS - problem is, I have zero experience handling ASP.net so far. While I think that handling the request object and saving it to the system should be easily doable, I am very insecure how to deal with the components of IIS itself.
AFAIK the source system (SAP) throws a POST directly at an URL, so I don't neccessarily need an actual form or page, but how do I weave it all together?

Do I still need a page or just a handler, how would I register it, to what extension?
I would be very happy if someone could give me a little jump start and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: I think you need a solution for Configuring IIS Application Request Routing, please review the video URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSvbjfsitmU

Comment: Take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472429/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-accept-post-requests